# On ubuntu-server with UI, the wifi connection fails without asking password

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant, systemd-networkd

I'm using a ubuntu-server 20.04 image as desktop (UI installed via tasksel).

I've been failing to set up a wifi connection for a week+ so here we are.

When using Network-Manager I can see my network SSID from the UI,  and with `iwlist wlp3s7 scan|grep ESSID` and nmtui. BUT whenever I try to connect (via the UI and via nmtui) I'm never prompted for a password.

networkd was configured by default (by subiquity). Both networkd and Network-Manager connects seamlessly with ethernet.

I have done and undone `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` and `/etc/wpa_suplicant.conf`. When triggering the later with `sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp3s7` I get that error message `wlp3s7: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Wine Hat" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED`

BTW these files contained my password (or it's hash) but I reverted them all and still don't get prompted from the UI or nmtui.

I've tried the "Edit connections interface" and most of time all its fields were greyed out. Sometime though I managed to key in my password with still no effect.
I'd like to say also that I know well this password and I factored me as error prone so I did copy/paste/reread. I didn't miss-spelled it.

```bsh
diag@diag-srv:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:9a:70:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:b0:8c:0a:05:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:bb:e2:f8:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

journalctl is composed of series of

```
Oct 17 19:57:13 diag-srv kernel: wlp3s7: send auth to a4:91:b1:f4:4d:1b (try 2/3)
Oct 17 19:57:13 diag-srv kernel: wlp3s7: send auth to a4:91:b1:f4:4d:1b (try 3/3)
Oct 17 19:57:15 diag-srv kernel: wlp3s7: authentication with a4:91:b1:f4:4d:1b timed out
```

and

```
Oct 17 19:45:49 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963949.3944] device (wlp3s7): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Oct 17 19:46:06 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963966.3303] device (wlp3s7): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
```

that ones are less frequent

```
Oct 17 19:36:03 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963363.7914] device (wlp3s7): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Wine Hat' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.

Oct 17 19:36:19 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963379.2776] device (wlp3s7): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 17 19:36:20 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963380.2786] device (wlp3s7): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 17 19:36:29 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <warn>  [1602963389.3083] device (wlp3s7): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Oct 17 19:36:29 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963389.3084] device (wlp3s7): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 17 19:36:29 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <warn>  [1602963389.3109] device (wlp3s7): Activation: failed for connection 'Wine Hat'
Oct 17 19:36:29 diag-srv NetworkManager[1104]: <info>  [1602963389.3114] device (wlp3s7): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ lspci|grep Network
03:07.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2760 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT2760 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 7
       bus info: pci@0000:03:07.0
       logical name: wlp3s7
       version: 00
       serial: ee:be:4c:25:c5:90
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.4.0-51-generic firmware=0.40 latency=32 link=no maxlatency=4 mingnt=2 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:21 memory:fe300000-fe30ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 1c:1b:0d:9a:70:48
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.1.186 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe100000-fe11ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fe120000-fe123fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:2a:f3:19:22
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
```

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

today I also ran these commands

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd
Removed /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-networkd.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/systemd-networkd.socket.
diag@diag-srv:~$ sudo systemctl enable network-manager
Synchronizing state of network-manager.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable network-manager
```

and in case that's useful there is that one also :

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION      
enp5s0   ethernet  connected     ethernet-enp5s0 
wlp3s7   wifi      disconnected  --              
docker0  bridge    unmanaged     --              
lo       loopback  unmanaged     --
```

when I search for my password over /etc/ I get these files out. the `.backup` are me trying to keep my changes but disabled. the wpasupplicant provides the hash of the password. The networkmanager is sure enough the responsible for the lack of a password prompt. but still my connection timeouts before establishing

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ sudo grep -ri "Password" /etc/
/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf:#  psk="Password" 
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml.backup:          password: "Password"
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wine Hat.nmconnection:psk=Password
/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf.backup:    psk="Password"
```

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s7    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: A4:91:B1:F4:4D:1B
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Wine Hat"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000003f7a46b4272
                    Extra: Last beacon: 9140ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000857696E6520486174
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050000110000
                    IE: Unknown: 42020000
                    IE: Unknown: 46053000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C081BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000400040
                    IE: Unknown: DD1D0050F204104A0001101044000102103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101040003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

Other "Cells" are are detected aswell but I want to connect to "Wine Hat"
I don't think I have access restriction as recently I've connected a new phone to that gateway without changing configs.
I've bee looking into the gateway's interface (http://192.168.1.1/) and here is the log line of when I fail to connect:

```
Oct 20 00:22:56 daemon.err  odhcp6c[5883]   Failed to send DHCPV6 message to ff02::1:2 (Permission denied)
```

Following up I [disabled the IPv6 connection](https://www.pcsuggest.com/disable-ipv6-linux/)

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ ping6 localhost 
ping6: connect: Cannot assign requested address
```

I still can see the IPv6 error message on my router (they seems to go by 2 or three), the top one is most recent:

```
Oct 20 22:08:27 daemon.err  odhcp6c[31292]  Failed to send DHCPV6 message to ff02::1:2 (Permission denied)
Oct 20 22:07:42 daemon.notice   odhcpd[2900]    Got DHCPv6 request
Oct 20 22:06:42 daemon.info odhcpd[2900]    Using a RA lifetime of 0 seconds on br-lan
```

Here is what a new scan returned. I haven't errased the previous one for the channel used for Wine Hat isn't the same anymore (even if I reenable IPv6). Because that following snippet is insanely long already I included more information about the wireless board capability and configurations.

```
diag@diag-srv:~$ iwlist scan
docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s7    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 98:1E:19:D1:00:CC
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BTHub6-3N9G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000088c37fd037
                    Extra: Last beacon: 27108ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B4254487562362D334E3947
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050401030000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0503005A0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0117FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A0001101044000102104700102EFC3DB37A5946E284D2D91B57763C95103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C0400BF0CB259820FEAFF0000EAFF0000C0050001000000C3020002
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180203001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: 9A:1E:19:D1:02:CD
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"BTWi-fi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000088c37fda7c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 27106ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0007425457692D6669
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050401030000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0500005A0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0117FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C0400BF0CB259820FEAFF0000EAFF0000C0050001000000C3020002
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 03 - Address: D2:05:C2:FD:9A:19
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Virgin Media"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000045d99ad2180
                    Extra: Last beacon: 11773ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C56697267696E204D65646961
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFF0000000000000000000001000000000406E6A70C00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500000200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 04 - Address: A4:91:B1:F4:4D:1B
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Wine Hat"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000012293cb18e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 27089ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000857696E6520486174
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050000130000
                    IE: Unknown: 42020000
                    IE: Unknown: 46053000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C081BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000400040
                    IE: Unknown: DD1D0050F204104A0001101044000102103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101040003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 05 - Address: C0:05:C2:FD:9A:19
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VM1885022"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000045d98c90180
                    Extra: Last beacon: 26774ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0009564D31383835303232
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 460573D000000C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFF0000000000000000000001000000000406E6A70C00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0805000F0200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD1D0050F204104A0001101044000102103C0001021049000600372A000120
          Cell 06 - Address: 52:DC:E7:92:CB:17
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000d4c28103a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 11741ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0015000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0117FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0104
                    IE: Unknown: DD3D0050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120101100154A61636F622773204669726520545620737469636B1054000800010050F2040009
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD12506F9A0902020025AB03060052DCE7924B17

diag@diag-srv:~$ iw phy #0 info
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short long limit: 2
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:10)
        * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
        * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x27e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            RX STBC 2-streams
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            No DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 2 usec (0x04)
        HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
        TX unequal modulation not supported
        HT TX Max spatial streams: 1
        HT TX MCS rate indexes supported may differ
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * set_qos_map
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8,
           total <= 8, #channels <= 1
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Supported extended features:
        * [ RRM ]: RRM
        * [ FILS_STA ]: STA FILS (Fast Initial Link Setup)
        * [ CQM_RSSI_LIST ]: multiple CQM_RSSI_THOLD records
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211 ]: control port over nl80211
```

Given the bitrates and frequencies displayed by my wireless card and according to [that article](https://itectec.com/superuser/iwconfig-command-not-showing-abgn/), the former seems to run under the 802.11g protocol. I'm actually confused since the lspci had shown earlier 802.11n, could that be caused by the obsolete WEXT API as [that same artice](https://itectec.com/superuser/iwconfig-command-not-showing-abgn/) says? In the mean time my router is configured for 802.11b/g/n so either should be good.

At this point, I'm out of ideas :/ thanks for reading :)

A special thanks ahead to Heynnema for the investigation.

Comment: Is wpasupplicant actually installed? It's not on a server installation. Check with `dpkg -l wpa* | grep ii`. Report back.

Comment: Thanks heynnema, indeed it is : ```ii  wpasupplicant  2:2.9-1ubuntu4.1 amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)``` I've tried and had the same issue with a live desktop image.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Are you using the NM GUI to configure your connections? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I had reverted my changes made on these files (and rebooted) but the symptomes didn't change.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist scan`. Are you trying to connect to "Wine Hat"? Do you have access control enabled on your router? Remember... start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. And when you add new data to your question, you have to let me know so that I know it's there, and can review it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @heynnema I've added iwlist data. I don't have access control enabled. I've found some more info from the router (see above)

Comment: I would have liked to see the full `iwlist scan` output, so I can see how many other networks are using channel 6 (and others). You might have a problem there. Two things... Go to your wireless network connection profile, and turn off IPv6, and see what happens. Also, the wireless signal is kind of weak. Try to move closer to the router and see what happens.

Comment: @heynnema thanks, I'll do it tonight (in 10h)

Comment: @hyennema I've disabled IPv6, then checked on the router for any changes but there are none I can see. Then I've appended the new ```iwlist scan```.

Comment: I've reviewed your latest information. I'm sorry, but I don't know where the problem is. If you finally figure it out, I'd love to hear about it.